# Chrome issue with custom webkit scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using scroll-snap-type:y mandatory; And Im customizing my scrollbar with these css styles :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #e0b078;
}
```

My issue is with chrome only because it works fine in Microsoft edge explorer.

When I click on an empty space on the ScrollBar's track area it must scroll to the section I've clicked or scroll step by step. but It jumps to the footer or header of the page.

I've created an online example on codepen that might be useful to solve the issue
I wasn't able to find a solution for this...

https://codepen.io/mehdicodecom/pen/gOQpXrb

Answer (score 0):

Change you css code like this

```
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y;
}
```

Hope it will solve you problem

Comment: But I wanted to use mandatory type for scrolling it has different way of scrolling. I think the default type is proximity